# Will cartographer ignore parts of robot that is scanned?

Tags: ros, cartographer, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Just a quick question,
Will cartographer automatically detect and ignore parts of the robot that is scanned by the LIDAR or do I have to somehow set it in the urdf file or somewhere else in the config?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281234/will-cartographer-ignore-parts-of-robot-that-is-scanned?/) by [Jnus](https://answers.ros.org/users/33021/jnus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2018-01-30**:
Not quite sure what you mean. The LIDAR will scan the environment not the robot. If you mean will it ignore the environment it's already scanned then it'll recognise an area of the map it's see before

Mark

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-01-30**:
Depending on the position of the LIDAR in the robot, it's possible that it sees part of the robot (e.g. some mounting parts)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-30**:
This is typically called `self filtering`, and as far as I know (but do prove me wrong please), `cartographer` does not do this.

**Comment by [Jnus](https://answers.ros.org/users/33021/jnus/) on 2018-01-30**:
Is there any guide/tutorial on how to do self filtering? Do I do it before passing lidar data to cartographer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out this package. http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters You need to filter the current scan topic and publish the filtered scan into a new topic.

---

Originally posted by [Maverobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/31254/maverobot/) with karma: 66 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jnus](https://answers.ros.org/users/33021/jnus/) on 2018-01-30**:
I will try it out. Thanks